# Set hidden <asp:Label> visible with jQuery show()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, label

Is there any way to set `<asp:Label>` visible by jQuery?

I have a label like this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCheckboxesError" Text="test" visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

and in js file I have this:

```
$("[id*=lblCheckboxesError]").show();
```

But its not shown. I have tried some solutions, but nothing works for me. any idea? thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `style="display:none;"` instead:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCheckboxesError" Text="test" 
   style="display:none;"></asp:Label>
```

`visible="false"` runs in the server (the server doesn't send the element to the browser)

`style="display:none;"` hides the element in browser so jQuery's `show()` works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Make sure the id is generated with same as given "lblCheckboxesError" in the html and style is set as "display:none" as show/hide acts on display property of style attribute. Then you could access the control as:

$('#lblCheckboxesError').show();
```

Template: $('#ID').show()